# How do I make kubernetes ingress run on http instead of https?

Tags: kubernetes

I've setup some test spring boot application in localhost kubernetes and was able to access them using ingress but they only work using **https**, I want to make them accessible in ordinary **http**.

Is there any specific configuration needs to be done?

EDIT:

I'm using docker desktop with built in kubernetes

ingress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: my-ingress
spec:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
              service:
                  name: my-service
                  port:
                      number: 8080
```

deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: my-service
    labels:
        app: my-service
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: my-service
    template:
        metadata:
            labels: my-service
                app: my-service
        spec:
            containers:
            - image: test/my-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
              name: my-service
              ports:
                  - containerPort:8080
       ... other spring boot override properties

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: my-service
    labels:
        app: my-service
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    selector:
        app: my-service
    ports:
    - name: 8080-8080
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
```

Comment: That's surprising, it usually works the other way around: you usually need to do more work to enable https than http. But your question is very non-specific: what is your kubernetes distribution: minikube, k3s, ...? What ingress plugin did you activate? What ingress class do you use? What's the spec of the ingress itself?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `ingressClassName: nginx`.

For docker desktop with built in kubernetes, I assume you have installed the NGINX Ingress Controller? Or maybe it was installed already?

Anyway, the NGINX Ingress Controller enforces HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect by default.

> By default the controller redirects HTTP clients to the HTTPS port 443 using a 308 Permanent Redirect response if TLS is enabled for that Ingress.
>
> This can be disabled globally using ssl-redirect: "false" in the NGINX config map, or per-Ingress with the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" annotation in the particular resource.

There's a lot of other things you can configure for NGINX HTTPS handling. See https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/